# How to update using formatted parametrized queries in Python?

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyodbc

I've to run an update statement for multiple rows but instead of directly using the float values, I have to make sure that the values are formatted (no scientific notation) before the update.

```
updatesql = " update table set [fieldname] = ? where dt = ?"  
data = (outputData.reindex( ['col1', 'col2'],axis='columns').to_numpy())
updatecursor.executemany(updatesql, data.tolist()) 
sql_conn.commit()
```

The above code works, except float values are not properly formatted. Is there a way to format the values while still using parametrized queries?

Comment: Scientific notation is just a *representation* of a floating-point value, not the value itself. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] where you show how to create the `outputData` DataFrame that can reproduce the issue (even if it is mocked, and not the actual process that you use). As it stands now your question is too vague to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to solve it using the following.

```
def shortenlength(numberToShorten):
    limited_float = "{:.15f}".format(numberToShorten)
    return limited_float

outputData['col1'] = outputData['col1'] .apply(shortenlength)
```